# How to change EditText cursor and bottom line color in xml?

Tags: android, xml

I need to change cursor color and bottom line color to `#FFFFFF` of EditText in xml.

How I can to do that?

[image]

My styles.xml :

```
<resources>

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@color/toolbar_text_color</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">#FFFFFF</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">#FFFFFF</item>
        <item name="android:editTextStyle">@style/EditTextStyle</item>
        <!--<item name="actionMenuTextColor">@color/toolbar_text_color</item>-->
    </style>


    <!-- Toolbar theme. -->
    <style name="ToolbarTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
        <item name="actionMenuTextColor">@color/toolbar_text_color</item>
        <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@color/toolbar_text_color</item>
        <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/hockeyapp_button_background_pressed</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/toolbar_text_color</item>
        <item name="android:background">@color/toolbar_bg_color</item>
    </style>

    <style name="EditTextStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.EditText">
        <item name="colorControlNormal">#FFFFFF</item>
        <item name="colorControlActivated">#FFFFFF</item>
        <item name="colorControlHighlight">#FFFFFF</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Definitinion of EditText :

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/ed_profile_id"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
    android:hint="Profile id"
    android:textColorHint="@color/white"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use material design EditText. Link for this [Material Edit Text Library](https://github.com/rengwuxian/MaterialEditText)

Gradle line to add:

```
compile 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:2.1.4'
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It helps!